# rake aborted! Ruby on rails, Plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ruby, plugin

Tive que entrar no mundo de Ruby a força para modificar um plugin de Wordpress, sou novato no Ruby, só é seguido dicas e não logro dar um jeito para resolver o problema. Seguindo os passos para fazer isto me encontro com este erro depois de inserir na consola o seguinte comando "rake setup".

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-social-metrics-tracker-1.6.1>rake setup

Do you want to develop on WordPress multisite right now? (y/n)y
WP-CLI 0.20.1
Using system WP-CLI command 'wp'
======================  CREATING WP DEV DB  ======================
$(wp foi inesperado neste momento.
======================  DOWNLOADING AND CONFIGURING WORDPRESS CORE AND TEST FILES  ======================
'bash' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
======================  CREATING WP-CONFIG  ======================
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - rm -f tmp/wp-config.php
tools/tasks/setup.rb:71:in ``'
tools/tasks/setup.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
tools/tasks/setup.rb:118:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => setup:wp_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Olho a última linha e insiro na consola "rake setup --trace" e presenta-se isto:
C:\MAMP\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\wp-social-metrics-tracker-1.6.1>rake setup --trace

```
** Invoke setup (first_time)
** Execute setup

Do you want to develop on WordPress multisite right now? (y/n)y
** Invoke setup:dev_db (first_time)
** Invoke requires_wpcli (first_time)
** Execute requires_wpcli
WP-CLI 0.20.1
Using system WP-CLI command 'wp'
** Execute setup:dev_db
======================  CREATING WP DEV DB  ======================
$(wp foi inesperado neste momento.
** Invoke setup:files (first_time)
** Execute setup:files
======================  DOWNLOADING AND CONFIGURING WORDPRESS CORE AND TEST FILES  ======================
'bash' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.
** Invoke setup:wp_config (first_time)
** Invoke requires_wpcli
** Execute setup:wp_config
======================  CREATING WP-CONFIG  ======================
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - rm -f tmp/wp-config.php
tools/tasks/setup.rb:71:in ``'
tools/tasks/setup.rb:71:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
tools/tasks/setup.rb:118:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => setup:wp_config
```

Em ambos casos o rake é abortado conforme imagem. Alguém poderia ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Este plugin parece depender do programa `bash` disponível em sistemas operacionais UNIX, como Linux. Desenvolver aplicações Ruby em ambientes Windows, apesar de possível, é extremamente difícil e não recomendado. A solução mais fácil seria rodar essa sua aplicação em um ambiente Linux.